# Windows SxS Redistributable Version Issue

Tags: windows-7, msvcrt, redistributable, winsxs

I have a program that is refusing to run on some Windows 7 machines. Using `sxstrace`, the executable claims to want Microsoft.VC80.CRT/MFC version 8.0.50727.6195 and 8.0.50608.0. See below.

```
> INFO: Parsing Manifest File C:\Program Files
> (x86)\PFPS\falcon\fvw.exe.   INFO: Manifest Definition Identity is
> (null).   INFO: Reference:
> Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.6195"
> INFO: Reference:
> Microsoft.VC80.MFC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.6195"
> INFO: Reference:
> Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50608.0"
> INFO: Reference:
> Microsoft.VC80.MFC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50608.0"
> INFO: Resolving reference
> Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.6195".
> INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
>     INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
>       INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
>         INFO: No publisher policy found.
>         INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
>       INFO: Begin assembly probing.
>         INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
>         INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.CRT\8.0.50727.6195__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.DLL.
>         INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
>       INFO: End assembly probing.   INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
>     INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
>       INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
>         INFO: Find publisher policy at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_policy.8.0.microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4940_none_516d712b0f495a45.manifest
>         INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
>       INFO: Begin assembly probing.
>         INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
>         INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.CRT\8.0.50727.6195__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.DLL.
>         INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\PFPS\falcon\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.DLL.
>         INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\PFPS\falcon\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.MANIFEST.
>         INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\PFPS\falcon\Microsoft.VC80.CRT\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.DLL.
>         INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\PFPS\falcon\Microsoft.VC80.CRT\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.MANIFEST.
>         INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
>       INFO: End assembly probing.   ERROR: Cannot resolve reference Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.6195".
> ERROR: Activation Context generation failed. End Activation Context
> Generation.
```

Using `mt.exe` showed me the same version requirements.

Hopefully unrelated, but the only machines I have been able to make it run on have Visual Studio installed.

I did as Hans Passant advised in a comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110184/winsxs-fails-to-load-vc-dlls), which lead me to install the x86 version of [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26347).

Before I installed the new redistributable I had the following:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable - KB2467175 version 8.0.51011
Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable (x64) version 8.0.61000
Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable (x64) - KB2467175 version 8.0.51011
```

After I install the supposed 8.0.50727.6195 redistributable, I end up with:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable version 8.0.61001
Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable (x64) version 8.0.61000
Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable (x64) - KB2467175 version 8.0.51011
```

I expected the top line of the "after" portion to be **8.0.50727.6195**. I'm obviously missing something. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Did I just get the wrong link three times in a row?

Additionally, what does the line `INFO: Find publisher policy at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_policy.8.0.microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4940_none_516d712b0f495a45.manifest` mean? Is it also dependent upon 8.0.5727.4940?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

8.0.50727.6195 is this security update. Make sure it is installed:

**MS11-025: Description of the security update for Visual C++ 2005 SP1 Redistributable Package: June 14, 2011**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2538242

Comment: Oh. I didn't realize it was just a patch, not the whole redistributable. I installed the patch as you directed, but the version number didn't change in the Programs and Features dialog. The application starts up now. I would still like to understand why it works without the proper version showing up, but this is a good start.

Comment: And for those who don't know about it (like me 20 minutes ago), you can get individual Microsoft Security Update binaries via catalog.update.microsoft.com.

Comment: you can also get this update via http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=26347